# How to make regex work in stylelint rule?

Tags: javascript, regex, stylelint

i want to specify allowed values properties for `'background'` and i made this

```
rules: {
        'declaration-property-value-allowed-list': {
            'background': ['/^linear-gradient\(.*\)$/', '/var/']
        },
    },
```

I want to make rule that allows only variables and linear-gradient function as property value and forbid hex / rgb / rgba etc. But linter doesnt take the value

```
background: linear-gradient(
            263deg,
            rgba(84, 145, 255, 0.24) 0%,
            rgba(169, 143, 207, 0.06) 30.85%,
            rgba(169, 143, 207, 0.06) 74.1%,
            rgba(172, 159, 126, 0.12) 100%
        );
```

error:

```
Unexpected value "linear-gradient( 263deg, rgba(84, 145, 255, 0.24) 0%, rgba(169, 143, 207, 0.06)  declaration-property-value-allowed-list
           30.85%, rgba(169, 143, 207, 0.06) 74.1%, rgba(172, 159, 126, 0.12) 100% )" for property                                                   
           "background"
```

Are some mistakes in my regex ? `/^linear-gradient\(.*\)$/`

Comment: Does `/^linear-gradient\([\s\S]*\)/m` work?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew also doesn't work

Comment: `/linear-gradient\([\s\S]*\)/`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it works almost as expected but in case when background has value like this 
```background: linear-gradient( 263deg, rgba(84, 145, 255, 0.24) 0%, rgba(169, 143, 207, 0.06) 30.85%, rgba(169, 143, 207, 0.06) 74.1%, rgba(172, 159, 126, 0.12) 100%), #fff;``` 
linter must throw an error because of #fff at the end, but it doesnt. i think regex should contains ```$``` and ```^``` to strictly specify start and end of the string.  But when i do this ```/^linear-gradient\([\s\S]*\)$/ ``` it also doesn't work and starts throw error on any kind of value with linear-gradient.

Comment: It does not work because you need to know what the text input is. If it does not end with `)`, you must find out what it really ends with. With `);`? Then use `/linear-gradient\([\s\S]*\);$/`. What is at the start?